# JSON schema + relative JSON-pointers: how to verify "confirm password" field

Tags: javascript, jsonschema, ajv

Here's my [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/):

```
{
  "required": [
    "username",
    "password",
    "confirmPassword"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "username": {
      "minLength": 3,
      "type": "string"
    },
    "password": {
      "minLength": 6,
      "type": "string"
    },
    "confirmPassword": {
      "const": {
        "$data": "1/password"
      },
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "type": "object"
}
```

Here's my data:

```
{
  "username": "abc",
  "password": "asdfasdf",
  "confirmPassword": "asdfasdf"
}
```

You can copy-paste those into [this online validator](http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/) to see what happens.

The `confirmPassword` field is failing validation with error message:

> Value "asdfasdf" does not match const.

I believe there is a problem with my [relative JSON pointer](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-luff-relative-json-pointer-00) but I can't figure out what the correct syntax is.

AFAICT, `1/password` means "go up one level, and then check the `password` property" but that doesn't appear to be the case. What's correct syntax?

The specific implementation I'm using is AJV which says it *does* [support relative-JSON-pointers](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv#data-reference).

Comment: @Amy The spec you linked is only for *absolute* JSON pointers, isn't it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turns out the only problem was that I forgot to set the [`$data` option](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv#validation-and-reporting-options) to `true`. e.g.

```
const ajv = new Ajv({
    allErrors: true,
    $data: true,
});
```